# How to show no result found from a AngularJS search?

Tags: angularjs, search

I am fetching data from an api and I am using it to search something. When the json returns no result how to show NO RESULT FOUND.

Html code

```
        <div class="item item-input-inset">
    <label class="item-input-wrapper">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Search" ng-model="search">
    </label>
    <button class="button button-small" ng-click="load(search)">
      Submit
    </button>
  </div>
  <section class="list">
       <article ng-repeat="object in news"> 
        <div class="item">


         <div ng-repeat="item in object.news">
        <p class="noWhiteSpace"><b>Available Size</b> - {{item.size}}</p>

         </div>

         </div>
         <div ng-repeat="item in object.news" class="button-bar bar-dark" >
  <a  ng-click = openUrl(item.url); class="button">button</a>

        </div>
      </article>
        </section>
        </ion-content>
      </ion-view>
    </script>
```

This is JS Code where I am fetching data from an api and also searching it.

```
 $http({

    method: "GET",
    url: https://news.com/json?limit=50"
  })
  .then(function(newsData){
   $scope.news= newsData.data.data.articles;
   $scope.hide();
    console.log(data);

  })

      $scope.load = function(search) {
     $scope.show();
  $http({
    method: "GET",
    url: "https://news.com/json?query_term=" + encodeURIComponent(search)
  })
  .then(function(newsData){
   $scope.newsto= newsData.data.data.article;
   $scope.hide();
    console.log(data);

  });
}

})
```

Comment: I have updated the **html** code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**html code**

```
 <h3 ng-if="noData">No Data Found</h3>
```

**js code**

add this code in *http*

```
if(!$scope.news){
      $scope.noData = true;
    }else{
      $scope.noData = false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
<section class="list">
    <div ng-if="news">
    <article ng-repeat="object in news">
        <div class="item">

            <img ng-src="{{object.medium_cover_image}}">

            <h2 class="noWhiteSpace">{{object.title}}</h2>
            <p class="noWhiteSpace">{{object.genres}}</p>
            <p class="noWhiteSpace"><b>Release</b> - {{object.year}} </p>

            <div ng-repeat="item in object.news">
                <p class="noWhiteSpace"><b>Available Size</b> - {{item.size}}</p>

            </div>

        </div>
        <div ng-repeat="item in object.news" class="button-bar bar-dark">
            <a ng-click=o penUrl(item.url); class="button">button</a>

        </div>
    </article>
    </div>
    <div ng-if="news">
        No news to show
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Update the answer

Comment: I have yet to check the result once i get the answer i will update  the answer

Comment: Its there , try now.

Answer (score 0):

```
<article ng-repeat="object in news" ng-if="news.lenght">
```

//show your result

```
<span ng-if="!news.lenght">No Result found </span>
```

**Updated with Fiddle link**

[link](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/28632/)

Comment: what is data you getting in here :  `$scope.news= newsData.data.data.articles;` ?,

Comment: Images,url,description etc

Comment: See this [fiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/28632/), and try to connect with your code. change url to see for no data

Comment: what if your success method crashes?, then `.catch()` will handle it for you. Its a best practice

Comment: So it will store previous data in case of failure right ...? And also will it also work in ionic aplication

Comment: yes, your scope data remains intact, till you refresh your app. Its javascript ofcourse will work with ionic.

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
<input ng-model='q'/>
```

and in ng-repeat

```
   <article ng-repeat="object in news|filter:q as result">
```

and in span

```
<span ng-if="results.length === 0">
      No results found...
    </span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't written code to catch service call failure.
By any chance, if such case is getting a failure response, then you haven't written code to handle that situation.

```
$http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: '/someUrl'
}).then(function successCallback(response) {
    // this callback will be called asynchronously
    // when the response is available
}, function errorCallback(response) {
    // called asynchronously if an error occurs
    // or server returns response with an error status.
});
```

Comment: Then where should i call this function